# Axaj Call without reloding the page?

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, jsp

I've a form with

`id="form" action="register.jsp" method="post".`

and that form has some input fields.

```
<button id="submit" class="k-button">Submit</button>
```

The following ajax code successfully sents the data to server **register.jsp**.

```
$(function() {
        $("#form").submit(function() {
            var userName = $("#username").val();
            var passWord = $("#password").val();
            var firstName = $("#firstname").val();
            var lastName = $("#lastName").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var dob = $("#datepicker").val();

            //var vars = "Username="+userName+"Password="+passWord+"Firstname="+firstName+"Lastname="+las tName+"Email="+email+"Date="+dob;

            var vars = {userName, passWord, firstName, lastName, email, dob};

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "register.jsp",   // your api or url for fetching data
            data: vars,   // your data coming from front end in json
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#output1").html(data);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                $("#output1").html("Not a successful connection!"); 
            }
        });
      });
    });
```

**Register.jsp**

```
<%
String user = request.getParameter("username");
session.putValue("userName",user);
String pwd = request.getParameter("password");
String fname = request.getParameter("firstname");
String lname = request.getParameter("lastname");
String email = request.getParameter("email");
String dob = request.getParameter("datepicker");

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user_info3","root","root");

Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs;

int i=st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO `new table`(user,pwd,fname,lname,email,dob) VALUE ('"+user+"','"+pwd+"','"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+email+"','"+dob+"')");
 %>

 Registration is Successfull. Welcome <%=user %>,
 Your Password is : <%=pwd %>, 
 FirstName : <%=fname %>, 
 LastName : <%=lname %>, 
 Email : <%=email %>, 
 and Date Of Birth is :  <%=dob %>,
```

My issue is that I want to display the the users enter data on the same page without reloding .But the above code redirects to register.jsp, after user clicks the submit button.

Comment: Simply don't use `form` or use `event.preventDefault();` on submit event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the button `type` to `button` and perform your `ajax`, this will prevent the page-reload. Also change this line `$("#form").submit(function() {` to `$("#submit").on('click', function() {` so that the ajax is triggered on the button click and the form is not submitted as you changed the button type to `button`

So HTML change:

```
<button type="button" id="submit" class="k-button">Submit</button>
```

Javascript change:

```
$(function() {
        //Add on click event to the submit button instead of posting the form
        //You could safely remove the form element from the DOM altogether
        $("#submit").on('click', function() {
            var userName = $("#username").val();
            var passWord = $("#password").val();
            var firstName = $("#firstname").val();
            var lastName = $("#lastName").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var dob = $("#datepicker").val();

            //var vars = "Username="+userName+"Password="+passWord+"Firstname="+firstName+"Lastname="+las tName+"Email="+email+"Date="+dob;

            var vars = {userName, passWord, firstName, lastName, email, dob};

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "register.jsp",   // your api or url for fetching data
            data: vars,   // your data coming from front end in json
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#output1").html(data);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                $("#output1").html("Not a successful connection!"); 
            }
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: I tried this, but it also doesn't save the data to MySQL.  it gives Not a successful connection. error.

Comment: @Mayurkandalkar I suspect that has something to do with the .jsp file you have displayed. You're question was how to submit the data server side without a page refresh. That has nothing to do with your question, that sounds as if you have a bad connection string or some other DB related issue. If that issue persists, make a new post with your DB question.

Comment: A Great thanks to you. But the above code which I've posted in question works fine with the DB. After the changes, it runs error function i.e Not a successful connection.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding e.preventDefault(), it will solve your issue. Shown like below to your method

```html
 $("#form").submit(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 }
```

or else Add button type and call your ajax post method

Answer (score 0):

By default, if you don't specify the `type` of a `button` element, it is of `type` `submit`. You probably just need to update your HTML like so

`<button id="submit" class="k-button" type="button">Submit</button>`

This will prevent the page from reloading.